# $authWithPassword always return "The specified password is incorrect."

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I  am trying to achieve authentication with password with angularfire (firebase).
The javascript is implemented with coffeescript (!).
creating users, and all other firebase functionality seems to works fine.

However, when trying login users with $authWithPassword, It always returns an error with "The specified password is incorrect." No matter what the password is.

The way it is implemented:
In coffeescript:

```
$scope.loginUser = ()->
        console.log("logging in! "+ $scope.loginEmail + " "+$scope.loginPassword)
        $scope.auth.$authWithPassword({"email": $scope.loginEmail,  "password": $scope.loginPassword})
        .then (authData)->
            $scope.authData = authData
            console.log(authData)
            $mdToast.showSimple("welcome!")
            return
        .catch (error)-> 
            console.log(error)
            $mdToast.showSimple("there was a problem")
            return
        return
```

.. and it always return "there was a problem... and console says that the problem was the password"
what went wrong? (I double checked - it is not the password.)

translation to javascript:

```
$scope.loginUser = function() {
  console.log("logging in! " + $scope.loginEmail + " " + $scope.loginPassword);
  $scope.auth.$authWithPassword({
    "email": $scope.loginEmail,
    "password": $scope.loginPassword
  }).then(function(authData) {
    $scope.authData = authData;
    console.log(authData);
    $mdToast.showSimple("welcome!");
  })["catch"](function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    $mdToast.showSimple("there was a problem");
  });
};
```

--- EDIT ---
The html markup that is used:

```
<md-card-content>
              <div>
                <md-input-container>
                  <input placeholder="email" type="email" ng-model="loginEmail">
                </md-input-container>
                <md-input-container>
                  <input placeholder="password" type="password" ng-model="loginPassword">
                </md-input-container>
              </div>
              <div><span></span>
                <md-button ng-click="loginUser()" class="md-primary">
                  <md-icon>person</md-icon><span style="font-size:16px">connect</span>
                </md-button>
              </div>
</md-card-content>
```

I want to mention, that even when hard-coding the username and passwords into the javascript, it still can't login. So it doesn't seems as a problem in the html part. In addition, the loginUser() function do fires, as I do get the error message in the console.

Comment: Where do you give authData to the ".then(function(authData))? I mean you never give this value to the function or I don't see it so when it try to set $scope.authData = authData;

Comment: In the main controller above this code I have...

ref = new Firebase('https://xxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com')
$scope.auth = $firebaseAuth(ref)
$scope.authData = $scope.auth.$getAuth()

Comment: but when you call the ".then(function(authData))" you are renaming the $scope.authData = **authData**; This **authData** is null or when you give it to the function?

Comment: I don't understand the question. the ".then" function is part of the $authWithPassword API as described in the angularfire documentation https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-users-and-authentication-authwithpasswordcredentials-options

Comment: does this show you anything? **console.log(authData);**

Comment: of course: "Error: The specified password is incorrect.(…)"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106361/discussion-between-alejandro93sa-and-dror-hilman).

Comment: The code looks correct at first glance. Can you try hard-coding the email+password to test? This will make it clear whether the problem is in reading from the view or in passing them to Firebase.

Comment: hard-coding the email and password gave the same results

Comment: May you please show us your HTML?

Comment: See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You need to provide enough detail for people to reproduce the issue and less terse responses to their attempts to coax this information from you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had to travel away from my computer. I will provide the HTML source soon.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, but I found the bug elsewhere in my code. The problem was in creating new users, I had a code that adds some characters to the passwords, and indeed the passwords that I was trying to login with where always wrong. So the code above works fine now. 
Thanks.